# MySQL EXISTS() really slow

Tags: mysql, exists

This query

```
SELECT
    itemID,
    locationParentID,
    locationID,
    categoryParentID,
    categoryID,
    itemTitle,
    itemDetails,
    itemAttributes,
    itemPictures,
    itemFeatured,
    itemSpotlight,
    itemAdded
FROM items
WHERE items.siteID IN('".$cfg['site']['siteShares']."') 
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sites_locations sl WHERE items.locationID  = sl.locationID AND siteID = '".$cfg['site']['siteID']."' LIMIT 1)
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sites_categories sc WHERE items.categoryID = sc.categoryID AND siteID = '".$cfg['site']['siteID']."' LIMIT 1)
    AND itemStatus = '1'
    AND itemAdded > '".$cfg['timestamp']."'
```

works but it takes upto 6 seconds

I could do with using `JOIN` as i'm guessing it will be quicker

here's what I have tried with `JOIN` but It returns all results instead of just the items which have a location in the `sites_location`s table.

```
SELECT 
    itemID, 
    locationParentID, 
    categoryParentID, 
    categoryID, 
    itemTitle, 
    itemDetails, 
    itemAttributes, 
    itemPictures, 
    itemFeatured, 
    itemSpotlight, 
    itemAdded 
FROM items LEFT JOIN sites_locations 
    ON items.locationID = sites_locations.locationID 
    AND sites_locations.siteID = items.siteID 
WHERE items.siteID IN('1,2')  AND itemStatus = '1'
    AND itemAdded > '1356048000' ORDER BY itemID DESC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: why do you use exists at all? looks like a plain cross-join (even natrual) would sort things out here

Comment: items table primary = itemID; sites_locations table primary auto AND locationID is relation;

Comment: @Najzero I am using EXISTS() because it works and I don't know any other way to get it working

Comment: @IanWilkinson You should use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I don't know why this question got voted down, but I took it back to zero. I'm finding unexpected slow performance with EXISTS too. In Oracle, using EXISTS is preferred to using DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates. But in MySQL, I"m finding the DISTINCT is nearly 10x faster than using EXISTS for a given query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you making a join on table **sites_categories** in second query .

Comment: Once I get it to work with the sites_locations I will the extend it to do the same on the sites_categories

Answer (score 0):

The `INNER JOIN` keyword returns rows when there is at least one match in both tables.

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).

that is the difference why you are not able to get values

[Check this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)